# Angular 5 ngIf inside ngFor - change the index to the actual included rows

Tags: angular

I have an input that filters ngFor items.
I want the index to indicate the amount of rows that are actually present after applying the filter.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwf5fa?file=app/app.component.ts

If you put "bob" in the filter, the result will be counting the real index, but i want the actual index of the present items.
this is the actual result.

```
3 = bobby
4 = bob
5 = bob the builder
```

this is what i want:

```
0 = bobby
1 = bob
2 = bob the builder
```

Component:

```
  @Component({
          selector: 'my-app',
          template: `
          <input type="search"  [ngModel]="search" (ngModelChange)="search = $event" />
          <div *ngFor="let item of myArray; let i = index">
            <span *ngIf="search == undefined ||  myArray[i].includes(search)">
            {{i}} = {{myArray[i]}}
            </span>
          </div>

          `
        })
        export class AppComponent {
          myArray = ["ronald","ron","dana","bobby","bob","bob the builder","ronald"];
          search : string;
        }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwf5fa?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: why dont you simply generate a new list with the resulting filtered items?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can overwrite the index in `ngFor`, but you can create a new array with the filtered items:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ryazgz?file=app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <input type="search" #searchField [ngModel]="search" (ngModelChange)="search = $event" (keyup)="filterArray(searchField);" />
  <div *ngFor="let item of filteredArray; let i = index">
    {{i}} = {{filteredArray[i]}}
  </div>

  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  myArray = ["ronald","ron","dana","bobby","bob","bob the builder","ronald"];
  filteredArray = [];
  search : string;

  constructor() {
    this.filteredArray = [...this.myArray];
  }

  filterArray(field) {
    let searchTerm = field.value;
    this.filteredArray = [...this.myArray.filter(item => item.includes(searchTerm))];
  }
}
```